# Azure Data Factory: Using ORC file as source or sink in data flow with ADLS gen2?

Tags: azure-data-factory, orc, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to create a Azure Data Factory dataflow from an Avro file source with some transforms, landing as an ORC file, both in ADLS gen2.  However, ORC does not seem to be an option for a dataflow sink.  I also tried as a dataflow source, and it was grayed out (see image below, ORC option is grayed out)

[image]

I've successfully used it in a Copy activity as a sink.  Haven't been able to find documentation though, other than that ORC is a compatible file type with ADF.  Has anyone been able to use ORC in a dataflow as either a source or sink, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Flow doesn't support ORC format file now.

You could reference the doucument [Supported source connectors in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-source):
[image]

We can not use ORC as the Source or Sink dataset.

Hope this helps.